# How to automatically start mate-terminal the CLI way on every system start?

Tags: cron, startup, mate-terminal

UPDATE2

Best approach as of now:

Mirroring of the GUI way.

Problem:
emacs launched along the way is restricted by being bound to the terminal-session:

What do you do, when you're like "Okay, done with emacs, for now, wanna enter some bash commands now." ? You suspend emacs by typing in Ctrl+z. That makes emacs go into the background and stop until you resume it from there once again.
But not, if you start mate-terminal & emacs like described here! Even more: In reaction to that unwanted outcome, if you then head for alternative route by ending emacs with Ctrl-x Ctrl-c, not only emacs is ended, but also the mate-terminal-session! Unwanted #2.
There is a walk-around, but it's a bit hacky - there MUST be better ways to handle this than doing the following:

```
Ctrl-alt-t (another mate-terminal-tab opens)
Ctrl-x Ctrl-c (end emacs and in the course of that weirdly also the 1st mate-terminal-tab)
emacs -nw (start emacs again, this time explicitely, manually causing it to be invoked as a "real, usual" session, also capable of responding to stop signals like typing in Ctrl+z)
```

Do you have any idea how to fix that last 2 problems?
That would be highly appreciated.

---

UPDATE - replies to the comment section - base posting after that:

I really wanna do it the CLI way - reducing my GUI dependence as a user. So, you think I'd better head into the direction of utilizing rc.local as desired? Haven't tried that, yet, just had it on my TODO list as plan B, in case the crontab approach can't work - assumed so far, that it can work with crontab. Why can't it, if crontab has dedicated elements for my use case, like '@reboot', and the 'reboot cronjob date' test ballon did work?! Btw, did the system user attempt on recommendation of internet video 'Linux Crash Course - Scheduling Tasks with Cron' - https://yewtu.be/watch?v=7cbP7fzn0D8 .

BASE POSTING:

I know! It sounds so simple, but I just can't make it work - although I've tried so many things.

You might think, 'duh, just add this line to your logged-in user, and that's it!'
`@reboot mate-terminal`
But it's not that simple.

What am I doing wrong? Where's that last part to complete the puzzle?
What I've tried and found out:

1st attempt: The GUI way

```
Trisquel-start-button in the left desktop corner at the bottom >
System >
Preferences >
Personal >
Startup Applications >
Tab 'Startup Programs' >
'add' >
Edit Startup Program
Name: Mate Terminal
Command: mate-terminal --full-screen --hide-menubar
Comment: Terminal >
Save >
Ensuring the activation box next to the new entry is checked
```

And you know what? It works. Kind of. Not very good:

```
System starts >
Gui with log-in window appears >
logging-in >
Desktop appears, with mate-terminal being right open >
screen blinks 2, 3 times with white screen >
mate-terminal is not the active window,
it's at the top of the desktop, covers everything by full-screen-mode,
but typing doesn't go into the terminal,
so, first I need to select mate-terminal by Alt+TAB,
making it the active window,
and only then what I'm typing goes into mate-terminal as input
and appears on the screen as output
```

That sub-optimal turn out made me dig deeper into the issue in the first place!

2nd attempt: Crontab

This is a small compilation of my many attempts, aiming to clarify things, which are important for crontab to work as desired or showcasing the degree to which things actually work out pretty well

Logged-in user

```
user@TechnoethicalX200T:~$ whoami
user
```

sudo-membership

```
user@TechnoethicalX200T:~$ cat /etc/group | grep sudo
sudo:x:27:user,automat
```

Availability of mate-terminal

```
user@TechnoethicalX200T:~$ which mate-terminal
/usr/bin/mate-terminal
```

Executing mate-terminal - it works

```
user@TechnoethicalX200T:~$ mate-terminal
(> new mate-terminal window popping up)
```

Availability of date - for comparism, we'll get to that

```
user@TechnoethicalX200T:~$ which date
/bin/date
```

crontab of logged-in user 'user'

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command

# @reboot date >> /tmp/test-file-date-collection
# Before un-commenting:
# - (File not existing)
# After un-commenting: Works!
# user@TechnoethicalX200T:~$ cat /tmp/test-file-date-collection
# Thu 23 Nov 08:54:30 CET 2023
# user@TechnoethicalX200T:~$ who -b
#          system boot  2023-11-23 08:54
# Conclusion:
# The logged-in user 'user' is capable of setting up a working reboot cronjob,
# with just specifying command name - not explicitely [full path]/[command name]

# Failed - syslog
# user@TechnoethicalX200T:~$ grep -C5 "mate-terminal" /var/log/syslog
# Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T systemd[1]: Starting Permit User Sessions...
# Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T cron[878]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
# Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T systemd[1]: Starting LSB: MD monitoring daemon...
# Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
# Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T dbus-daemon[888]: Unknown username "whoopsie" in message bus configuration file
# Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T CRON[891]: (user) CMD (mate-terminal)
# Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T dbus[888]: [system] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
# Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T avahi-daemon[876]: Successfully called chroot().
# Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T avahi-daemon[876]: Successfully dropped remaining capabilities.
# Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
# Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T avahi-daemon[876]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
@reboot mate-terminal
(<<< newline character behind last line - both, of the whole crontab and of each active cronjob in it
That detail turned out to be important for crontab to work properly, and not on all systems that automatically gets added,
I had to input it manually)
```

And to make a long story short, which also can be deduced from the fact, that the test ballon 'reboot cronjob date' worked:
Yes, cron.service on my system is enabled and activated (currently running, as always)

I've also created a system user, gave it sudo priviledge and let it do the cronjob -

```
automat:x:1001:1001::/home/automat:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

in vein.

```
user@TechnoethicalX200T:~$ grep -C5 "mate-terminal" /var/log/syslog
Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T systemd[1]: Starting Permit User Sessions...
Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T cron[878]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T systemd[1]: Starting LSB: MD monitoring daemon...
Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T dbus-daemon[888]: Unknown username "whoopsie" in message bus configuration file
Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T CRON[891]: (user) CMD (mate-terminal)
Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T dbus[888]: [system] AppArmor D-Bus mediation is enabled
Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T avahi-daemon[876]: Successfully called chroot().
Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T avahi-daemon[876]: Successfully dropped remaining capabilities.
Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
Nov 24 18:25:06 TechnoethicalX200T avahi-daemon[876]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
--
Nov 24 18:38:47 TechnoethicalX200T systemd[1]: Started inputattach for Wacom ISDv4-compatible serial devices.
Nov 24 18:38:47 TechnoethicalX200T systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
Nov 24 18:38:47 TechnoethicalX200T systemd[1]: Starting LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems...
Nov 24 18:38:47 TechnoethicalX200T avahi-daemon[899]: Found user 'avahi' (UID 109) and group 'avahi' (GID 118).
Nov 24 18:38:47 TechnoethicalX200T systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
Nov 24 18:38:47 TechnoethicalX200T CRON[912]: (automat) CMD (mate-terminal)
Nov 24 18:38:47 TechnoethicalX200T systemd[1]: Starting Console System Startup Logging...
Nov 24 18:38:47 TechnoethicalX200T avahi-daemon[899]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
Nov 24 18:38:47 TechnoethicalX200T avahi-daemon[899]: avahi-daemon 0.6.32-rc starting up.
Nov 24 18:38:47 TechnoethicalX200T avahi-daemon[899]: Successfully called chroot().
Nov 24 18:38:47 TechnoethicalX200T systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start the GNUstep distributed object mapper...
```

So, where's the problem? Seriously, why doesn't it work?
Why after reboot just the desktop appears - without a mate-terminal window?
Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: `crontab` is definitely the wrong tool. And having a different user start a mate terminal for you is even more wrong. Work on the first solution

Comment: Sounds more like an issue with the desktop environment - which one are you using?

Comment: upsidedown now is question Your! 1/2 Please don't put updates at the top. Instead, update or rewrite your question with the new information so that it reads cleanly. (If you like, pretend you're writing it from scratch but this time with more/newer details.)

Comment: 2/2 Having come back to revisit this question I'm trying to work out what it is that you want. Starting emacs in a terminal session when you log in? Starting emacs like this but being able to quit it and have interactive access to shell running in the underlying terminal session? (If it's the second, why not just open a new terminal window?) It's got really rather confusing